# Renomear arquivos e mover para fora do diretório Python

Tags: python

eu estou desenvolvendo um script python, que ele precisa acessar uma pasta e dentro dessa pasta tem 3 pastas que tem varios arquivos

exemplo:

```
Pastaprincipal
    |
    | ---- pasta1
             | ---- arquivo.pdf
    |
    | ---- pasta2
             | ---- arquivo.pdf
    |
    | ---- pasta3
             | ---- arquivo.pdf
```

o que eu preciso fazer e renomerar esses aquivos de extenção `PDF` e depois retira-los das pastas movendo para a `PastaPrincipal`.

ficando assim

```
   Pastaprincipal
    |
    | ---- pasta1
    |
    | ---- pasta2
    |
    | ---- pasta3
    | ---- renomeado.pdf
    | ---- renomeado.pdf
    | ---- renomeado.pdf
```

aqui esta o meu código

```
import os
from time import sleep

def Files(filepath):
    print('Lendo a pasta principal [{pasta}]...'.format(pasta=os.path.basename(filepath)))
    sleep(1)
    for files in os.listdir(path=filepath):
        print(files)
        os.chdir(files)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    filess = input('deretório principal:')
    Files(filess)
```

quando eu uso o `os.chdir()` para eu poder entrar dentro das pastas ele me retorna um erro `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'pasta1'`.

o que eu quero fazer é renomear antes de pode mover os arquivos.

alguém pode me ajudar por favor :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.chdir` é uma abordagem ruim para trabalhar com arquivos em várias pastas,
por que o diretório atual é mudado - e o seu programa tem que ficar sabendo "onde está".

O melhor sempre é trabalhar com os nomes dos diretórios junto com os nomes dos arquivos, em todo lugar - mudar o diretório como fazemos no terminal vai ser dor de cabeça. Atéo Python 3.5, para juntar o diretório com o nome do arquivo, o mais recomendado era usar `os.path.join` -  o programa vai ficando grande.

Do Python 3.6 em diante, a biblitoeca pathlib foi aperfeiçoada e pode fazer um monte de coisas legais em manipulação de arquivos - basicamente você usa um objeto do tipo `pathlib.Path` no lugar de uma string com um nome de arquivo ou diretório - e isso é um objeto que tem um monte de métodos diferentes - inclusive
um equivalente ao `os.listdir` e um `.rename` - além de um que busca arquvos em subdiretórios por tipo.

Mais ainda - em todos os sistemas operacionais modernos, o método que renomeia um arquivo é o *mesmo* que move ele pra outro diretório - então não faz sentido você renomear pra depois mover.

Com a estrutura que você põe no exemplo, dá pra fazer algo como:

```py
from pathlib import Path

principal = Path("Pastaprincipal")


for contador, pdf_path in enumerate(principal.glob("**/*.pdf")):
    novo_nome = principal / f"renomeado{contador:02d}.pdf"
    pdf_path.rename(novo_nome)
```

(A `/` com o objeto Path cria um outro Path indicando o arquivo dentro de um diretório, igual no terminal - o `enumerate` simplesmente aproveita
o `for` e gera uma sequência de números, de forma que cada
arquivo tenha um nome único)

Esse código assume que você vai rodar o programa de uma pasta acima da "Pastaprincipal"  - se quiser que funcione de qualquer lugar, ponha 
o caminho absoluto para esta pasta. Se quiser que funciona da pasta
em que você está quando chama  o programa no terminal, (iss e, você faz `cd Pastaprincipal` no terminal e chama o programa), mude para ele começar no diretório atual com `principal = Path(".")`

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, funcionou obriagdo

Comment: se funcionou, considere marcar esta reposta como aceita - você ainda pode dar votos para outras respostas que ache legais.

Answer (score 0):

Eu testei o seu código num diretório na minha máquina (MacOSX) e para mim funcionou normalmente para entrar nas pastas que eu tenho neste diretório. Então, eu não consegui replicar o erro. Eu só tive que verificar se o arquivo é de fato um diretório. Meu código ficou assim, eu só não tentei mover os arquivos de diretório:

```
import os
from time import sleep

def Files(filepath):
    print('Lendo a pasta principal [{pasta}]...'.format(pasta=os.path.basename(filepath)))
    sleep(1)
    for files in os.listdir(path=filepath):
        print(os.getcwd()+"/"+files)
        if os.path.isdir(os.getcwd()+"/"+files):
            print(files)
            os.chdir(os.getcwd()+"/"+files)
filess = input('diretório principal:')
Files(filess)
```

Com relação ao erro especificamente, parece ser um erro do Windows quando o mesmo não é capaz de achar o diretório que você especificou. Então realmente eu não tenho como replicar. Tenta ver se você está digitando o diretório corretamente, se o mesmo realmente existe, e se há uma maneira diferente de especificar o diretório no seu sistema operacional.  Nesta [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324107/windowserror-error-2-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified)(em inglês), eles explicam o que fazer quando se tem esse erro.

Comment: OI Thiago obrigado cara, para eu renomaer os arquivos continudo dentro das pastas eu vou usar o os.rename(), listando os arquivos e depois renomea-los.

Answer (score 0):

Os erros que esta tendo pode ser por algum motivo que não iremos poder testa, mas você deveria usar tratamentos de erros para evita-los

Segue uma pequena modificação que realizei ja renomeando e movendo os arquivos para o local de destino

```
import os
from time import sleep


def Files(filepath):
    print('Lendo a pasta principal [{pasta}]...'.format(pasta=os.path.basename(path=filepath)))
    sleep(1)
    BASE = os.path.abspath(path=filepath)
    n = 1
    for files in os.listdir(path=BASE):
        if os.path.isdir(path=os.path.join(BASE, files)):
            print(files)
            for file in os.listdir(path=os.path.join(BASE, files)):
                print(file)
                if os.path.isfile(path=os.path.join(BASE, files, file)):
                    try:
                        os.rename(src=os.path.join(BASE, files, file), dst=os.path.join(BASE, 'New_name({}).pdf'.format(n)))
                        n += 1
                    except Exception as err:
                        print('Arquivo nao pode ser renomeado e movido pelo erro: {}'.format(err))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    filess = input('deretório principal:')
    Files(filess)
```

---

### Dica

Se estiver usando o python 3.5 acima, você pode trocar o uso do `.format()` para as `f strings` deixando mais elegante

e caso use o python 3.8 (Versão mais atual até o momento) pode utilizar o novo `:=` colocarei como ficaria o seu codigo caso utilizasse a versão mais recente

```
import os
from time import sleep


def Files(filepath):
    print(f'Lendo a pasta principal [{os.path.basename(filepath)}]...')
    sleep(1)
    BASE = os.path.abspath(path=filepath)
    n = 1
    for files in os.listdir(path=BASE):
        if os.path.isdir(path=files):
            print(files)
            for file in os.listdir(path=(fs := os.path.join(BASE, files))):
                print(file)
                if os.path.isfile(f := os.path.join(fs, file)):
                    try:
                        os.rename(src=f, dst=os.path.join(BASE, f'New_name({n})'))
                        n += 1
                    except Exception as err:
                        print(f'Arquivo nao pode ser renomeado e movido pelo erro: {err}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    filess = input('deretório principal:')
    Files(filess)
```

Comment: oi Guilherme, ele me retorna esse erro rename() missing required argument 'dst'

Comment: Testes aqui e nao encontra nenhum erro, verificou se colocou o codigo acima corretamente?, estranho você obter esse erro sendo que esse argumento esta no codigo acima, vou muda algumas coisas que pode ser que resolva, só uns 5 min

Comment: Verifique agora, e se por acaso tornar da erro, se puder me informe a versão que esta rodando o Python e tente copiar o código daqui https://onlinegdb.com/rkTRBmbAH

Comment: Obrigado pela sua ajuda Guilherme funcionou.

Comment: nada, e não esqueça de colocar e marcar todas as repostas que foram uteis e relevantes S2